# c++ How in runtime to give the user a suitable exception by the error code?

Tags: c++, exception, polymorphism, runtime

I need to create some interface which will able to give me suitable exception by code(int).
Exception Inheritance:

```c
BaseException : public std::exception {...};
DerivedException1 : public BaseException {...};
DerivedException2 : public BaseException {...};
```

I need a function like `get(int code)` to solve this problem:

```c
try {
    int code = foo();
    throw get(code);
} 
catch(DerivedException1& e) {...}
catch(DerivedException2& e) {...}
catch(BaseException& e) {...}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: In this case user want to handle different exception by different ways and so it nessasary that each exception has its own catch-block.

Comment: You can't get what you want from throwing an `int`. They may have different values, but the signature is still `int`. Every number you throw is routed to the same place: a handler for `int`

Comment: I don't think this is possible.. Even if you did `std::exception* getcode(int)` and throw a pointer to an exception, only the `std::exception*` catch block will trigger. It won't dynamically determine which kind of exception was thrown and throw the correct one. Maybe someone might know, but afaik, even throw `std::any` of underlying type being an exception doesn't work.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, I think what it is impossible too. I tried many different ways to solve it, but nothing can help even `std::variant`. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`throw` throws by value, so you have slicing with:

```
std::exception& e = /*...*/;
throw e; // throws a std::exception, not possible derived class
```

Then you might do something like:

```
void as_exception(int error_code)
{
    switch (error_code)
    {
        case 0: return; // Not an error.
        case 1: throw DerivedException1();
        case 2: throw DerivedException2();
        // ...
    }
}
```

With usage similar to:

```
try {
    const int code = foo();
    as_exception(code);
} 
catch (const DerivedException1& e) {...}
catch (const DerivedException2& e) {...}
catch (const BaseException& e) {...}
```

Similarly, you might use [std::exception_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) the following way:

```
std::exception_ptr as_exception_ptr(int error_code)
{
    switch (error_code)
    {
        case 0: return nullptr; // Not an error.
        case 1: return std::make_exception_ptr(DerivedException1());
        case 2: return std::make_exception_ptr(DerivedException2());
        // ...
    }
}
```

With usage similar to:

```
try {
    const int code = foo();
    const auto eptr = as_exception_ptr(code);
    if (eptr) {
        std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
    }
} 
catch (const DerivedException1& e) {...}
catch (const DerivedException2& e) {...}
catch (const BaseException& e) {...}
```

Comment: The question is, how can I get away from throwing an exception function to a function just returning an object to the user.

Comment: I understand your question as: "how to implement `throw get(code);`"? (which is done on my part with `as_exception(code);`, as `std::exception& get(int)` would have slicing issue). If it is not your question, I still don't understand what you want.

Comment: Brandon in top of the post explain my problem :)

Comment: Clarified slicing and add another alternative.

Comment: Wow.. I didn't know about `exception_ptr`. Nice nice. Definitely added to my knowledge base :)